# How to fetch all the movie details from IMDB

Tags: feed

I am working on wordpress website and want to fetch all movies/tv data from imdb by using movie/tv id E.G tt2527336. I wanna fetch everything, i mean Director, Stars, Release Date, genre, storyline, country, feature post and language. Is there way that all data will add in post by adding imdb post id?

Comment: This is a question for IMDB's tech support. It's not a WordPress-specific one.

Comment: BTW data mining violating the terms of use of IMDB. http://www.imdb.com/conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pat J is right but even so, I think there's an unofficial API that provides that kind of feature: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imdb-api